# Cannot retrieve html from website

Tags: c#, html, dom, browser, domdocument

I'm loading this [page](http://www.zippysearch.org/zippysearch/?cx=partner-pub-9019877854699644%3At1iell5gp8b&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=wiggle%20wiggle&sa=Search&siteurl=zippysearch.org%2F&ref=&ss=) *[possibly NSFW]* in my WebBrowser
When the WebBrowser.ReadyState is ready i tried to see in WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument, WebBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml, WebBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml but is not the page that I see in my WebBrowser.

```
WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
b.Navigate(url);
WaitBrowserLoading(b); //wait browser to complete loading
MessageBox.Show(b.Document.Body.OuterHtml);    
MessageBox.Show(b.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
```

None of the last two functions return the page that I can see when I analize it with Chrome.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How can we make any suggestions without seeing the code you're using?

Comment: What are the differences that you see; what would you expect to see? Without knowing what you're expecting, it's tricky to answer.

Comment: @AdrianWragg try to load the page in your borwser, and get the html. Then compare it with b.Document.Body.OuterHtml or b.Document.Body.OuterHtml, this two functions should return the same html that you get from your browser

Comment: That's a horrible example page to use; is there a reason why you're looking at that one? Also, are you using Chrome's browser tools or just "view source"?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I need to get the html of that page, it's not an example.
I'm using chrome's tools, so I need something that works like those

Comment: @AdrianWragg answer instead of marking as NSFW

Comment: I've added that warning in case someone else saw your question and was in an environment where the content of that link could cause them embarrassment; I don't see an issue in doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right result was in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml